# One time login screen on ios

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication

I'm creating an application and on the user first time use I will need them to give me their API Token to access the application, but I just need this login to show up one time, and after I will store the token on a NSUserDefaults.

My question is, I'm using storyboards and theoretically the login screen would be my root view... but after I have the token I want to skip this part, so how would I do it? should I create a separated xib file just for the login screen?

Then on the app delegate I would check if the Token is present and either call the xib or the storyboard file. Not sure if this is the best approach, does anyone would recommend something more efficient?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Add  stoyboardId for login and home view controller in storyboard

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 NSString *identifier;
 BOOL isSaved = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"loginSaved"];
 if (isSaved)
  {
   identifier=@"home";
  }
 else
  {
   identifier=@"login";
  }
UIStoryboard *    storyboardobj=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *screen = [storyboardobj instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
[self.window setRootViewController:screen];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: on the IF, the identfier is suppose to call a segue? or what type should I declare the identifier variable?

Comment: also the storyboardobj is what I set on the storyboard ID as per your screenshot, right?